# db5 error(-30969) from dbenv->open: BDB0091 DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch

Tags: oracle, rpm, alien

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and trying to unzip rpm file like

```
sudo alien --scripts -d oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

I am getting like

```
error: db5 error(-30969) from dbenv->open: BDB0091 DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 -  (-30969)
error: cannot open Packages database in /root/.rpmdb
```

Any one please help me

Answer (score 12):

This has nothing to do with Oracle. Remove `~/.rpmdb/` directory and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the Oracle web site, and then poked about google for a good bit of time on this one.  Frankly, I think you are looking at a very difficult installation, and you will need to spend ***a lot*** of quality time with your search engine to make this work.  Oracle does not love Ubuntu very much!

The easiest way to implement Oracle that I found, is to run Oracle Linux, a RedHat derivative(?) as a VM in VirtualBox, at which point Oracle Express should install seamlessly.

In fact to make it even easier, you can download a pre-installed VM with a relatively current version of Oracle Linux, and Oracle Express 12g [at these pages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html#php). The "Service Delivery Platform VM" looks like a good bet.